# Handling Subclass / Superclass records extracted from a database in python

Tags: python, oop, object

I have a python application and a postgresql database, which has two tables that are related to each other:

"Equipment" stores records with information about types of equipment eg description, picture, and an id field

"Item" stores records about individual items of equipment, e.g serial number, and an id field.

I have created a class for each of these and currently have a get(id) method which retrieves data from the database and stores it in an instance of the class, and create() and update() methods which take data from the class instance and store it in the database.

I would like to have "Item" be a sub class of "Equipment" such that when you access "item.description" you get the description of the equipment. How I manage this sub class such there is only one instance of each "Equipment" for many instances of "Item".

Is it possible to change the parent instance of a subclass instance after you have created it?

Edit: Added class below as requested, Item class should have same methods as Type Class

```
class Equipment:
def __init__(self, bookingid=None, description=None, category=None,
             replacementprice=None, forcelabel=None, image=None):
    """Class to hold Equipment Data"""
    self.id = None
    self.bookingid = bookingid
    self.description = description
    self.category = category
    self.replacementprice = replacementprice
    self.forcelabel = forcelabel
    self.image = image
    self.stamp = None

def get(self, equipmentid):
    """retrieve equipment from database"""
    data = itemops.getequipment(equipmentid)
    self.id = data[0]
    self.bookingid = data[1]
    self.description = data[2]
    self.category = data[3]
    self.replacementprice = data[4]
    self.forcelabel = data[5]
    self.image = io.BytesIO(data[6])
    self.stamp = data[7]

def create(self):
    """create type in database"""
    returned = itemops.createequipment(self)
    if returned is not None:
        self.id = returned[0]
        self.stamp = returned[1]
    return self.id

def update(self):
    """update equipment in database"""
    self.stamp = itemops.updateequipment(self)

def refresh(self):
    """Update equipment instance if necessary"""
    if self.stamp != itemops.getequipmentstamp(self.id):
        self.get(self.id)
        return True
    else:
        return False
class Item:
def __init__(self, equipmentid=None, barcode=None, serial=None):
    self.id = None
    self.equipmentid = equipmentid
    self.barcode = barcode
    self.serial = serial
    self.eventid = None
    self.out_noteid = None
    self.in_noteid = None
    self.temp = False
    self.stamp = None
```

Comment: Does the Item class inherits from the Equipment class? Also can you post your classes?

Comment: @Adamantoisetortoise added the classes, at the moment it doesn't inherit as I don't know how to do what I am describing, but I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need an attribute in your Item class (`equipmentisd` I guess) that references to an Equipment attribute `id`.
Then you can use your attribute `equipmentid` to look in your database for an istance of the class Equipment where `id==equipmentid`.
So your method for the Item class to display the attribute `description` of your Equipment class would look like this:

```py
def display_equip_description(self):
        data = itemops.getequipment(self.equipmentid) # gets the Equipment instance which 'id' is equal to the specified 'equipmentid' (attribute of Item)
        return data.description # return the description of the specified instance.
```